# Angular 9 migration changed tsconfig.app.json

Tags: angular9, angular-cli-v9

Why it changed from

```
"include": [
   "src/**/*.ts"
 ]
```

to

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

I know for what exist *.d.ts files. Question - why does it changed in Angular 9?